# How is code with an unset global variable not returning 'nobody'?

Tags: netlogo

I have a student who created a global variable called random-patch and a patch variable called elevation. They then used elevation to randomly choose a patch to set random-patch to. Problem is the code is running and choosing a patch without setting the patch variable elevation. I understand it is automatically set to zero but shouldn't this code usually come up with nobody? Any help understanding the issue here would be appreciated.

Code:

```
globals [ random-patch ]

patches-own [ elevation ]

to setup
  ca

  set random-patch one-of patches with [ elevation = (random 50) ]

;Also still reports a patch if only the pre to-setup code is entered and the
;following is entered on the interface observer console:

show one-of patches with [elevation = (random 50)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a really subtle error. The reason it is not returning `nobody` is because it constructs the agentset before selecting from it. What it is doing is testing each patch independently and drawing a random integer for each. The following code separates these two steps.

```
globals [ random-patch ]

patches-own [ elevation ]

to setup
  clear-all
  let zeros patches with [ elevation = (random 50) ]
  type "Patches with zero: " print count zeros
  set random-patch one-of zeros  print random-patch
end
```

If you are using the standard settings, there are 1089 patches. 1/50 of the random draws will return 0 so 1/50 or around 22 will patches will satisfy the condition and be in the implicitly constructed patchset.

Change the `random 50` to `random 100000` in your original code and you will likely get `nobody`. It will also operate as you expect if you separate out the draw (so `let roll random 50` then `set random-patch one-of patches with [ elevation = roll ]`